# Unable to switch between windows - Unable to get browser message displayed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button in a newly opened browser window after clicking on a button in main window. Each time a message is displayed:

> Unable to find element on closed window

Here is the code I am using:

```
public  Manage Administrators() {
 String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
 clickButton(waitUntilElementIsPresent(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Administrators')]"))));
  Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String windowHandle  : handles)
        {
        if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
           {
           driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          clickButton(Users);

          driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); 
           }
        }
 return PageFactory.initElements(driver, Manage.class);
```

It seems the new window opens, but is not visible to Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for new window to open. This can be done something like the below:

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
int prevWndCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
clickButton(waitUntilElementIsPresent(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Administrators')]"))));

// Waits for 60 seconds
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

// Wait until expected condition (Window count increases) met
wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

   public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {

      // Return true if window count increases, else return false
      return d.getWindowHandles().size() > prevWndCount;

   }

});
Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String windowHandle  : handles)
   {
      if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
      {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        clickButton(Users);
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); 
      }
   }

return PageFactory.initElements(driver, Manage.class);
```

See if this helps!